# android sdk realtime audio record

Tags: android, audiotrack, android-audiorecord

I use this code to record and play back recorded audio in real time using the [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) and [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html)

```
package com.example.audiotrack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int freq = 8000;
    private AudioRecord audioRecord = null;
    private Thread Rthread = null;

    private AudioManager audioManager = null;
    private AudioTrack audioTrack = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[freq];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
        final int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(freq,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);


        audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, freq,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB, bufferSize);

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.ROUTE_HEADSET, freq,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB, bufferSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);



        audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(freq);
         final byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        audioRecord.startRecording();
        Log.i("info", "Audio Recording started");
        audioTrack.play();
        Log.i("info", "Audio Playing started");
        Rthread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);                                    
                        audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("Error", "Read write failed");
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Rthread.start();
    }

}
```

My problem :

1.the quality of audio is bad

2.when I try different frequencies the app crashes

Comment: I don't know why you're having the other problems, but 8KHz PCM isn't very good quality. Have you tried 44100 to compare? Also try using THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO instead.

Comment: Agree with @PeterJ - 8KHz PCM won't give good quality but it depends on what you are recording. For mono though, 22050 should give enough quality rather than 44100.

Comment: thank you Peter, Squonk. I change the frequency to 44100 and 22050 but I get error when I launch the application

Comment: unfortunately, app has stoped

Comment: @JeffBic Find the stacktrace output in the logcat and edit your question to include it. That will contain information about why the application crashed. With that we may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Could not get audio input for record source 1

Comment: 1) Your setThreadPriority doesn't make sense, it tries to change priority of UI thread, useless.
2) in AudioRecord constructor, you can't use AMR_NB from MediaRecorder, read docs!

Comment: Hey jeff did you get any solution for this ?. if so can you please provide your solution, cause i am currently looking for same solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Audio quality can be bad because you are using AMR codec to compress audio data. AMR uses compression based on acoustic model so any other sounds than human speech will be in poor quality

Instead of

`MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB`

try

```
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
```

AudioRecord is low level tool, so you must take care of, parameters compatibility on your own. As said in documentation many frequencies are not guranteed to work.

So it is good idea to go through all combinations and check wich of them are accesible before trying to record or play.

Nice solution was mentioned few times on stackOverflow, e.g here 
[Frequency detection on Android - AudioRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376780/frequency-detection-on-android-audiorecord)

check `public AudioRecord findAudioRecord()` method